# Как реализовать очередь запросов на обычном веб хостинге

Tags: php, mysql, sql, база-данных

У меня есть телеграм-бот, который работает по принципу запрос-ответ.

Но так как в будущем пользователей будет больше - надо создавать очередь. При чем с приоритетом, так как есть сообщения, на которые надо ответить немедленно, а есть автоматические, которые 5-10 секунд могут подождать.

Это так же сделано для того, чтобы не превысить лимит в 30 запросов/секунду.

Следующая проблема - время выполнения скрипта. Связь обрывает на 30 с, в то время как крон может срабатывать только каждую минуту.

Если делать редиректом - запросы следующего крона и текущие могут либо перекриться (бан) либо 5-6 секунд пауза, что так же не хорошо - много потерь.

Вопрос: Можно ли как-то новым кроном остановить старый крон? Или возможно есть нормальная библиотека, предназначена для подобных задач?

Comment: Как по мне, **queue** в **Laravel** отличное решение. Один из самых простых способов организации фоновых задач (таких как отправка письма, например) — делегировать их скрипту в cron-е через базу данных. То есть записывать задачу с аргументами в таблицу-очередь, а кроном эту очередь разбирать по таймеру. Если по каким-то причинам это не подходит (например, из-за скорости реакции или нагрузки на бд), то наверное смотреть в сторону gearman. (источник - https://qna.habr.com/q/35823)

Comment: @MoloF я по сути так и делаю, вопрос в том, как избежать накладок и пауз между кронами. Пишу на чистом php, и у меня только веб хостинг пока что, сервера нет.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно завести таблицу в которую писать все что надо отослать боту. Можно с колонкой приоритет. Любой из обработчиков, будь то запрос от клиента или запуск по крону при необходимости что то отправить только добавляет работу в эту таблицу.

Завести вторую, сигнальную таблицу в которой будет лежать ровно 1 запись. Любой обработчик в конце работы (можно после того, как завершит работу с клиентом (на сколько я понимаю средства у php для этого есть)) **в транзакции** читает сигнальную таблицу с опциями `for update skip locked`. Если запрос не вернул запись - значит кто то другой ее сейчас держит, а значит работает, ничего больше не делаем, завешаемся. Если запись удалось прочитать, значит в данный момент более никто не пытается ничего отсылать. Читаем таблицу с очередью рассылок в порядке поля приоритета, с нужной скоростью шлем сообщения, удаляем из очереди. Стоит обратить внимание на такие настройки как максимальное время работы скрипта, что бы его сервер не прибил слишком быстро.

И да, конечно это костыль, на случай, что у вас на хостинге невозможно запустить отдельный, постоянно запущенный процесс, который бы выполнял задачи из очереди и в остальное время спал в ожидании работы. (возможно на более приспособленных для таких целей, нежели MySQL, системах вроде брокеров сообщений)

Comment: Решил создать запись в бд: Когда крон запускается - он меняет ее на wait (условно) Крон, который работал до этого перед каждым запросом эту запись проверяет, и если видит wait - останавливается, записывает free. Новый крон проверяет циклом видит free, записывает working и начинает работу. И так цикл. Скрипт работает 63 секунды примерно, этого достаточно. Вы написали что-то похожее. Думаете мой вариант будет работать корректно?

Comment: @shumik_UA Есть опасность, что скрипт как нибудь некорректно завершиться или сервер перезагрузиться и в таблице останется значение wait и крон больше не заработает. Поэтому я и предложил запись и работу с блокировкой mysql. потому что блокировка mysql будет жива только если жив скрипт который ее взял

Comment: ага.. Хорошая идея. Спасибо)

Comment: А что если использовать register_shutdown_function?

Comment: @shumik_UA Примерно это я и имел ввиду под фразой "_(можно после того, как завершит работу с клиентом (на сколько я понимаю средства у php для этого есть))_". Просто в интернете бегло это нашел, но до конца не понял, отпустит оно клиента или нет

Comment: А, реально. Понял)) Спасибо огромное! Скрипт уже работает и стабильно)